# Passing A Null Value in a Function's Optional Parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, null

I have a function that checks my database to see if a record already exists. If the record does exist then it returns the id for that record, if it doesn't exist then it creates a new record and returns the new id.

```
Friend Shared Function GetLogType(LogType As String, Optional Description As String = "")
    If GlobalVar.db.users.References.Count(Function(t) t.Description = LogType And t.DescriptionLong = Description) > 0 Then
        Return GlobalVar.db.users.References.First(Function(t) t.Description = LogType And t.DescriptionLong = Description).RefID
    Else
        Dim Ref As New Reference
        Ref.RefTypeID = 2
        Ref.Description = LogType
        Ref.DescriptionLong = Description
        Ref.Active = True
        Ref.CreateDate = Now
        Ref.UpdatedDate = Now
        GlobalVar.db.users.Entry(Ref).State = EntityState.Added
        GlobalVar.db.users.SaveChanges()
        Return GlobalVar.db.users.References.First(Function(t) t.Description = LogType And t.DescriptionLong = Description).RefID
    End If
End Function
```

This function checks two fields in the database to verify whether or not the record exists: `Description` and `DescriptionLong`.  The problem is occasionally `DescriptionLong` is allowed to be `NULL`in the database, however my function will automatically return a value of `""` for `DescriptionLong` when it saves a new record.

I have tried to allow the function to input a `NULL` value and check for a `NULL` value by doing this:

```
Friend Shared Function GetLogType(LogType As String, Optional Description As String = "")
  Dim DescVal As String
  If Description = "" Then
    DescVal = Nothing
  Else
     DescVal = Description
  End If                

  If GlobalVar.db.users.References.Count(Function(t) t.Description = LogType And t.DescriptionLong = Description) > 0 Then
    Return GlobalVar.db.users.References.First(Function(t) t.Description = LogType And If(DescVal = Nothing, 1 = 1, t.DescriptionLong = DescVal)).RefID
  Else
    Dim Ref As New Reference
    Ref.RefTypeID = 2
    Ref.Description = LogType
    Ref.DescriptionLong = DescVal
    Ref.Active = True
    Ref.CreateDate = Now
    Ref.UpdatedDate = Now
    GlobalVar.db.users.Entry(Ref).State = EntityState.Added
    GlobalVar.db.users.SaveChanges()
    Return GlobalVar.db.users.References.First(Function(t) t.Description = LogType And If(DescVal = Nothing, 1 = 1, t.DescriptionLong = DescVal)).RefID
  End If
End Function
```

But the function ignores `NULL` values all together so if `DescriptionLong` is `NULL` in the database it will not pass the first If statement and the function will create a new record every time.

Basically what I want is for The optional parameter `Description` to either be `NULL` or be `> ""`, and have the database return the id of the matching record, or create the new one. Instead if `DescriptionLong` is `NULL` in the database and `DescVal` is `Nothing`in the function it will create a new record every time regardless of whether or not a record with the same values already exists in the database.

Another solution I have found is that it does work if I allow the function to simply pass `Description` as `""` but this isn't ideal.

Comment: Have your tried changing your If Statement to 'If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Description) = True Then DescVal = Nothing'?

Comment: @JohnGalt DescVal is already being given the value nothing

Comment: empty string <> null.  @JohnGalt wants you to check if `Description` is null because you are only checking if the string is empty, at the moment.

Comment: @ps2goat why would description be null if it has a default value of ""

Comment: Can you change the default value for Description to Nothing? 'Optional Description As String = Nothing'. Then test if it remained as Nothing (eg. Null) or if there is something there.

Comment: @JohnGalt The issue isn't the functions ability to pass a `NULL` value to the database, it does that just fine.  The issue is if `DescriptionLong` is `NULL` in the database it creates a new record everytime.  For example, if I call `GetLogType(LogType:="Redirect to Page")` it will create a new record in the database EVERYTIME I call it because I don't define `Description`. What it should do is see that there is already a record with a value of "Redirect to Page" in the `LogType` field and `NULL` in the `DescriptionLong` field and return that records ID.

Comment: Your question does not reflect what you are asking in the comments.

Comment: @ps2goat perhaps you should reread the post my friend.  My post reflects exactly what I'm asking in the comments. **From the post**:"Basically what I want is for The optional parameter Description to either be NULL or be > "", and have the database return the id of the matching record, or create the new one."

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead ::

```
GlobalVar.db.users.References.First(Function(t) 
    t.Description = LogType And 
    t.DescriptionLong = If(DescVal = Nothing, t.DescriptionLong, DescVal)).RefID
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: `DescriptionLong` is a string, your solution would return an integer.  Also the ID I am trying to return needs to match on both fields `LogType` and `DescriptionLong`

Comment: @aaronmallen, how would it return integer, what did i do is simple check if DescVal is nothing than compare t.DescriptionLong with t.DescriptionLong itself and if it is not nothing than compare t.DescriptionLong with provided value.

Comment: `RefID` is an integer

Comment: I just change the inner pattern rest of the things are same as per your code

Comment: Im sorry I totally misread your code because its on multiple lines lol I will give that a try.

Comment: @aaronmallen, no problem, however i broke this in multiple lines for better readability ;)

Comment: I can certainly understand readability however visual basic wont pass it unless its single line. I will test this Monday, if it works I'll give you a check mark for sure. Also see my edit of your answer tell me what you think.

Comment: @aaronmallen yeah but for other users and even for your it would be better for understanding.

Comment: I dont think vb.net treats nothing and null as the same thing this goes through the function and then cant return anything because it doesnt find a value that matches.